# mysql server not connecting in command line

Tags: command-line, mysql, localhost

When I try to connect to my local MySQL installation on Ubuntu 21.04, I receive the following error:

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'nishant'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

[image: Screenshot of Error]

If I don't execute the above command then it does not connect to the server by sending output as:

```
No connection. Trying to reconnect...
ERROR 1049 (42000): Unknown database 'system'
ERROR: Can't connect to the server
```

How can I connect to the local MySQL installation?

MySQL Server Version: 8.0.27
CPU: AMD Ryzen5 5600u

Comment: The second error does not seem connected to the first. That said, have you confirmed that there is a `nishant@localhost` account on the MySQL installation? This may be different from a `nishant@%` account, depending on how you've configured MySQL.

Comment: Also, you should copy and paste that stuff from your terminal.

Comment: @matigo , i have only one account named "nishant"

Comment: @Thunderbird , i dont understand what stuff ? maybe this one ?  [ https://drive.google.com/file/d/1eec1vPBcCVlHcaIl6fiTEuEtuOaq8xw1/view?usp=sharing ]